# How can I adjust text to html without having a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails app sends email, and the content is just like this.

```
....
<p>
<%= raw @message.body %>
</p>
....
```

In email it should show something like this

```
Apple

Banana
Kiwi
```

However, the result is

```
AppleBananaKiwi
```

Yes, it doesn't have `<br>` between each.
I'm using the gem called `Mailboxer` and it take care of everything about this.
So I don't have Message model.

If I want the result with `<br>`(Return and Blank Line), how can I do that?

Comment: What is content of @message?

Comment: The content in second block:)

Comment: Try adding `\n` to the end of words?

Comment: could you please show that in answer?

Comment: @PavelS Could you show that in answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `simple_format` which takes care of converting `\n` to `<br>`:

```js
<%= simple_format @message.body %>
```

or `gsub`:

```js
<%= raw @message.body.gsub("\n", "<br />") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are setting `@message` inside a controller. If so you can use whitespaces easily. Just like this:

```
@message = "
Apple

Orange
Banana"
```

You can even style it like ASCII art.

```
@message = "

Apple
------

Banana ========> Orange
-----------------------
Banana ========> Orange
-----------------------
Banana ========> Orange
-----------------------"
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for lack of my explanation. First block in my question is html format. So I think I have to use `<br>` instead of actual blank line.

Comment: Sure. If that's HTML you can use <br>. If you have double quotes inside your HTML code you should consider to use single quote while defining @message.

Comment: `@message` could be input by the users so it comes from form.

Comment: `@message = params[:formdata]` ?

Answer (score 1):

So to have it with white spaces the simplest way would be

```
<pre>
 <%= raw @message.body %>
</pre>
```